# Laravel - Can a conditional join be accomplished with an Eloquent relationship?

Tags: sql, laravel, join, eloquent

How can the following be accomplished with Eloquent relationships? Posts can be bookmarked by multiple users, each user can only bookmark any given post once (the record is deleted if the bookmark is removed). I want to retrieve all of the posts with indicators of whether the currently logged in user has bookmarked them.

```
SELECT p.*, NOT(ISNULL(b.PostId)) Bookmarked
FROM Post p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT PostId FROM Bookmark WHERE UserId = {{ Auth::id() }}
) b
ON p.PostId = b.PostId
```

Comment: Not really a conditional join, it's a standard left join.  What specifically can't you figure out?  Did you try using leftJoin() with the query builder?

Comment: Yes no problems using the query builder. Wondering specifically if this can be accomplished through Eloquent model relationships i.e. a hasOne on each Post that is conditional on Auth::id()

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution is to create a pivot table, something like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // Your users table
});

Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // Your posts table
});

Schema::create('post_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
});
```

Than in your `Post` model define a [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship:

```
public function bookmarkUsers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Your\User\Model');
}
```

And than in your controller you can retrieve the bookmarked posts by a user:

```
//  [other stuff]
$posts = Post::whereHas('bookmarkedUsers', function($query) {
    $query->where('id', '=', Auth::id());
})->get();
```

Comment: That's effectively how my tables are set up. However, I'm trying to retrieve all the posts regardless of whether they've been bookmarked or not, but with an indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```php
$posts = Post::withCount(['bookmarks as bookmarked', function($query) {
    $query->where('UserId', Auth::id());
}])->get();
```

This requires a `bookmarks` relationship:

- Either a `BelongsToMany` relationship to the `User` table.
- Or a `HasMany` relationship to the pivot table (a bit faster, but requires a pivot model).